# React import file from previous directory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

I want to import a js file named 'usercontent.js' in react component but the current js file is in Component Folder and the file to be included in in the folder Conponent Container of which Component folder is a subfolder
e.g.
Component Folder contains usercontent.js and Component Folder.
and Component Folder conatins the current js file in which I want to import usercontent.js file
Please Help

Comment: Why do you want to import a file whether you can import a component or required function from that file?

Answer (score 1):

you can use '../' for availability Before newfolder